Is there a name for the number of '9's in numbers such as 0.999 (where it would be 3)?
I am doing an optics simulation involving transmission and reflection coefficients very close to 1, such as 0.999.  While I was an undergraduate student, a professor mentioned that, in certain fields, people characterise such numbers by the number of '9's after the dot.  I tried to find any mention of this on the internet, and a name for that number of '9's, but didn't find anything.
Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Incidentally,

The formula for that number of '9's in the number x is -log_10(1-x).
This might well be an engineering question.
ChatGPT suggests that that number of '9's is called 'nines'.  Makes some sense, but the rest of the internet seems to be agnostic to this term.


I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics.

You can extrapolate this as a repeating decimal, $0.\overline{9}(3)$, although strictly speaking repeating decimal is such when it never terminates, i.e. number of $9\text{'s}$ would be infinite in this case.

This type of figure is used in system availability specifications. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability#Percentage_calculation

@MarkH, so it is called 'nines', at least in system availability specs.  Thanks, very helpful.

@VincentThacker, I had hoped (and I am still hoping) that there was a term that was used in optics, so that the audience of my simulation understands without me explaining.

@AgniusVasiliauskas, I think you are right in saying that the repeating decimal description is about cases where there are infinitely many, but periodic, digits.  But it is a good starting point, and I have started to click my way through various links on the page you referenced.  Thanks!

@AgniusVasiliauskas 0.999 with infinitely many repeating 9's is equal to 1.

This is a question about standard terminology used in experimental physics research. I wouldn't close it.

@user34722 See point 2 in this post.

@VincentThacker Note that points 1 and 3 mention notation and terminology, while point 2 mentions notation only. (This question is about terminology, not notation.)

@VincentThacker True, as well as $1.000 \ldots 1$ with infinite number of zero digits in between is also simply 1. And ? I have tried to resolve OP question about closest possible terminology, not about where infinite digit sequence leads to. It's a different question, to which OP isn't interested.

I've heard 'nines' used frequently in quoting the purity of a material, and it turns out that this is a standard, though informal term. Wikipedia has this to say:
"Nines are an informal logarithmic notation for proportions very near to one or, equivalently, percentages very near 100%."
It apparently also comes up commonly in purity of industrial gases and system up-time in computer services. Mathematician Terence Tao proposed it as a measure of risk here (this is where I first heard it named).
However the most relevant and standard unit to use in these cases is probably to quote one minus your quantity of interest in dB (decibels). This is the standard way of quoting loss, transmission and reflection coefficients of optical and microwave components, and is much more common than nines. It also maps one-to-one with nines:
0.9 transmission: -10 dB loss
0.99 transmission: -20 dB loss
Etc.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability#Percentage_calculation
